# Prove or disprove: Let k ∈ N. If $k^2 + 5k$ is odd, then $(k + 1)^2$ + 5(k + 1) is odd.

Tags: solution-verification, alternative-proof

I have a question regarding the correctness of my proof (and the point of error in case of its incorectness), since the logic varies from the given answer proof.

**Statement**

> Prove or disprove: Let k ∈ N. If $k^2 + 5k$ is odd, then $(k + 1)^2 + 5(k + 1)$ is odd.

**Textbook proof**

> Assume that $k^2 + 5k$ is an odd integer, where k ∈ N. Then $k^2 + 5k = 2ℓ + 1$ for some integer ℓ. Hence, $(k + 1)^2 + 5(k + 1) = k^2 + 2k + 1 + 5k + 5 = (k^2 + 5k) + (2k + 6) = (2ℓ + 1) + (2k + 6) = (2ℓ + 2k + 6) + 1 = 2(ℓ + k + 3) + 1.$
> Since ℓ + k + 3 is an integer, $(k + 1)^2 + 5(k + 1)$ is an odd integer.

**My proof**

Case 1: k is odd. Then k = 2a+1, a $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$. Then

> $k^2 + 5k = (2k+1)^2 +5(2k+1) = 4k^2+4k+1+10k+5 = 2(k^2+7k+3).$

Since $k^2+7k+3\in\mathbb{Z}$, $k^2+5k$ is even.

Case 2: k is even. Then k = 2b, $b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then

> $k^2+5k=(2b)^2+5(2b)=4b^2+10b=2(2b^2+5b)$

Since $2b^2+5b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $k^2+5k$ is even.

Hence, the statement is true vacuously.

Comment: How could $k^2+5k$ be odd?

Comment: @lulu My proof is based on the fact that it is not, and achieving a vacuous truth.

Comment: Consider the simpler argument based on $(k + 1)^2 + 5(k + 1)=k^2+5k+2(k + 3)$

Comment: But it's just a one line argument.  $k^2+5k=k(k+5)$ and $k,k+5$ have opposite parities.

Comment: Thank you! Did think that my proof sounds way too redundant, which is why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Wtf why is the textbook proof so complicated? Is it just to show how proving sth like this would work?

Comment: Yes, that's my point.  What you wrote is correct, but unnecessarily wordy.  As to the official solution, perhaps they had the induction step in mind and failed to notice that the problem was vacuous.

Comment: @LegNaiB That is exactly it, and on the next page an example providing an alternative proof similar to mine is demonstrated lol. Just jumped into asking for verification since I was pretty sure my logic is sound, but should have just looked ahead in the textbook.

Comment: @lulu You are exactly right, exactly that (induction step)is stated on the next page. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Oh, no worries at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is a vacuous truth, your proof is correct. However, you could simplify it even more by using modular arithmetic:

Case 1: $k$ odd, so $k\equiv 1 \mod 2$, so we have
$$
k^2+5k \equiv k^2+1\cdot k \equiv 1 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 2
$$
and similarly for case 2 that $k$ is even, i.e. $k\equiv 0\mod 2$:
$$
k^2+5k \equiv 0 + 5\cdot 0 \equiv 0 \mod 2
$$
Then you don't even need to multiply anything out.

Or in fact as @lulu mentioned, just noting that $k(k+5)$ is a product of two different parities resulting in an even number.

Comment: Thanks! Will remember the technique.